# ATI Radeon 5770 Eyefinity failure

Tags: amd-radeon, eyefinity

I have this ATI Radeon 5770 Eyefinity problem 2 times per day
http://www.youtube.com/v/JFFxzv7818Q
With the last drivers for win 7 and 3 24'' monitors with 1920*1200
any suggestions?

Comment: How are the monitors cabled?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup using xFx HD 5770 graphics card. It is powering three DVI-panels like this :

- Monitor #1 connected through DVI.
- Monitor #2 connected through DVI.
- This display port cable from Dinodirect is connected to the Display port on the card : http://www.dinodirect.com/wholesale-display-port-male-mini-display-port-female-adapter-cable.html. This cable is then connected to the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter from Apple - http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A. With a DVI cable the adapter is finally connected to monitor #3.

I have never seen the issue you are reporting, so its hard to offer any solutions. But at the very least check if you are using an active adapter. AMD maintains a list of valid adapters on this page : http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx.

Comment: I don't use adapters

Comment: The hp monitor has display port

Comment: @nmout
Could you describe how the monitors are connected, i dont quite understand what the "I dont use adapters" comment means.

For Eyefinity you need to use an Active adapter. So if you are using a passive adapter right now, it would explain your problems, as it is only certified to work up to a certain resolution.

See here for example of using only a passive adapter : http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/279385-15-success-eyefinity-passive-adapter . Note that the resolution mentioned is not as high as your resolution.

Comment: @nmout : http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/279498-15-displayport-adapter-eyefinity says that these configurations work : "2 DVI + 1 VGA will work on a passive DP-VGA adapter. " OR "3 DVI requires an active DP to DVI adapter. " (Last one is my setup)